# Difference between driver and provider

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

What is the difference between driver and provider in database? Is there are any explanation will be grateful.

sample : `ADO.NET driver for MySQL` vs `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"`

Comment: Same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429026/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the MSDN Forum:

> Driver is a program installed on a workstation or a server; it allows programs to interact with a Database Management System (DBMS). Such as, JDBC driver provides database connectivity through the standard JDBC application program interface (APIs) available in J2EE.
>
> A data provider is a set of libraries that is used to communicate with data source. Such as, SQL data provider for SQL, Oracle data provider for Oracle, OLE DB data provider for access, excel and MySQL. It serves as a bridge between an application and a data source and is used to retrieve data from a data source and to reconcile changes to that data back to the data source.

Source: [MSDN-Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/67ada271-125f-44ad-8ac7-43d95f68b2e9/whats-the-difference-between-database-driver-and-data-provider?forum=sqldataaccess)

Comment: still not quite clear. Let me give you a scenario which might make things more clear. Machine A has got SQL Server installed with few databases. Machine B has got SSMS installed with the help of which we see database contents. On Machine C, there is a .Net exe running which connects with databases installed on Machine A and writes into its table using C# ADO .Net classes. Now can you  elaborate as to on what all machines database driver will be installed and on what all machines database provider will be installed?

Comment: Is it correct to say that a data provider (set of *.dll files) ultimately uses a database driver to interact with the database for CRUD operations?

Comment: @RBT, maybe this quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity#Drivers) would help: "An OLE DB-ODBC bridge consists of an OLE DB Provider which uses the services of an ODBC driver to connect to a target database. This provider translates OLE DB method calls into ODBC function calls."

Comment: https://community.qlik.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-463585-52718/db-full-diagram.png

Comment: Yes @RBT A provider is a Set of libraries that used to communicate with data source. It serves as a bridge between an application and a data source. Providers can include (or based on) a single or multiple database drivers.

Answer (score -3):

Provider is a connectivity with particular database like Sql Server, Oracle, but we import namespaces like `using system.data.msdaora`, `using system.data.sqlclient`.

After write connection class it takes string connection string takes 4 statements uid, pwd, database, server.

After open connection by using `cn.Open` method.

After executing statements.

After connection close.